# Path file issue when uploading csv file via laravel form to database

Tags: html, database, laravel, csv, upload

I want to upload a csv file to my database via a laravel form. I can only insert file if the file is stored into public folder. How can I correctly set path with fopen function?

When submitting form, my code uses only the csv that already exists in public folder and not the csv I try to upload. Except from the csv I also pass some other data to my controller. How can I alter code to receive form file and not public folder stored file?

1) Below is my form excerpt. At the bottom lines I try to upload the file.

```
<body>

    <form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/hard">

        {{csrf_field()}}

        <section>
        <br>
            <legend><i><b> Complete Data Below</b></i></legend>
        <br>
        </section>

        <section>   
        Choose program:
            <select name="sc" id="xaos">

            <optgroup label="postgraduates">
                @foreach($transport as $y)
                    <option value="{{$y->object_id}}">{{$y->object_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </optgroup>

            </select>
        </section>

    <br>

        <section>
        ID number: 
            <input name='am' type='number' min="1000000" max="1999999" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('1000000 < Value < 1999999')">
        </section>

        <br>

        <section>
        Select Language:
            <select name="language" id="lang">
                    <option value="GR"> Greek</option>
                    <option value="EN"> English</option>
            </select>
        </section>
        <br>
        <section>
        <label for="upload-file">select csv file</label>
            <input type="file" name="upload-file"> 
        </div>
            <input type='submit' name='upload' value="Submit!">
        </section>

    </form>
    <br>
    <br>

</body>
```

2) And below is my controller code excerpt which handles file imported.

```
public function job(Request $p)
    {
        $a1 = $p -> get('sc');
        $a2 = $p -> get('am'); 
        $a3 = $p -> get('language'); 




    $f_rownum = 0;

    if (($handle = fopen ( 'MOCK_DATA.csv', 'r' )) !== FALSE) 

    {
        while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, ';' )) !== FALSE )
        {
            $ac1=$data[0];
            $ac2=iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8", $data[1]);
            $ac3=iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8", $data[2]);
            $ac4=iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8", $data[3]);
            $ac5=$data[4];
...............
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel documentation you can store your csv file into the storage like this:

```
public function storeFile(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->file('upload-file')->store('{directoryName}');

        return $path;
    }
```

The above code store your file in storage and returns tha path which you can save it into your DB.

For retrieving the file, you can use this code if you want to force user to download the file:

```
return Storage::download('{pathWhichYouSavedInDB}');
```

or you can retrieve the content of the file by using this code:

```
$contents = Storage::get('{pathWhichYouSavedInDB}');
```

[I add the extra response which I wrote in the comments]
fopen requires a full-path url of the stored file to be able to open it. So you can get the file url and then pass it to the fopen function like this:

```
$url = Storage::url('file.jpg');
```

Or you can not to use fopen at all and just use the $contents which you already retrieved with

```
$contents = Storage::get('{pathWhichYouSavedInDB}');
```

Comment: Hello Matin. Thanks for replying. I just want user to upload a csv file. Then this file is stored in DB and code uses the other data inserted in form to run a query. How should I edit fopen to receive file from form and store it in my DB table?

Comment: @Konstantinos Hi; fopen requires a file to open it. So you must pass the file full-path url to fopen. You can get the stored file (which I assume you store it via the store function I gave you in the answer) with url funcation: $url = Storage::url('{pathWhichYouSavedInDB}');      Hope It Helps

Comment: @Martin I try to work out your answer with my code.. But this does not work so far. Does my form as it is, send file to controller? I added to my controller this line $path = $p -> file('upload-file')->store('C:\'); but dd($path) gives me a strange result (incorrect).